# common custom http header parameters in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, http

In the react, I would like to push a custom header ( user-id and auth ) in the HTTP header so that it will be available in all the HTTP methods. How do I inject like in angular?

Thanks,
Raja K

Comment: what library do you use for http requests?

Comment: I am not using any library. I am simply using fetch() method. Can you suggest me any library to use ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AXIOS library. reference [Link](https://github.com/kinny94/burger-builder-react/blob/master/src/axios-orders.js)

1. You can set Global axios defaults

   ```
   import axios from 'axios';

   axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com';
   axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
   ```

You can add the separate file for axios configure **Ex**: **axios-test-http.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});

export default instance;
```